# After change varchar max length, do I have to update Entity Framework

Tags: asp.net, database, entity-framework

I have production application asp.net webform with Entity Framework database first. After I noticed I had one `varchar` column size is too short. I changed it on my local database side. Run it and failed. I have to update Entity Framework from database, then succeed. But I couldn't see any change on the `.edmx` file.

Now I expanded the `varchar` size on live database. Do I need republish my local copy to make this change?

Comment: Thanks Marc_S for your correction.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> entities that reflect a table schema, so if that is changing it will break EF

[Refer Entity framework mapping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5533713/table-mapping-problem)
[image]

This Max Length highlighted in image was generated from the database scheme. Changing those will break the EF